# Django Prepopulate ModelForm with Table Record

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create an Edit for that allows the user to scroll through a table and click a button existing in each row to edit the data within a modal.

The issue that I am running into is when I try to prepopulate the form with the existing values. How would I convert the EditCommunicationsForm below to display the current values of the row that you selected edit for?

forms.py

```
class CommunicationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Communications
        fields = "__all__"

        widgets = {
            'project':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter your Project Name'}),
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter a short Title'}),
            'intent':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control','height':'50px','placeholder':'Describe the intent and desired outcome of the communication'}),
            'date':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select a Date'}),
            'channel':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'content_type':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select a Content Type'}),
            'audience':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter the Audience(s)'}),
            'status':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select the Status'}),
            }

class EditCommunicationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Communications
        fields = "__all__"

        widgets = {
            'project':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','initial':'Project 123'}),
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter a short Title'}),
            'intent':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control','height':'50px','placeholder':'Describe the intent and desired outcome of the communication'}),
            'date':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select a Date'}),
            'channel':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'content_type':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select a Content Type'}),
            'audience':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter the Audience(s)'}),
            'status':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select the Status'}),
            }
```

views.py

```
def communications(request):
    comms_list = Communications.objects.order_by('id')
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_form = CommunicationsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        edit_form = EditCommunicationsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:7000/polls/communications/',{"new_form":new_form,"edit_form":edit_form,'comms_list':comms_list})
    else:
        comms = Communications.objects.get(id=**ID**)
        new_form = CommunicationsForm()
        edit_form = EditCommunicationsForm(initial={"project":comms.project })

        query = request.GET.get('search')
        if query:
            postresult = Communications.objects.filter(id__contains=query)
            comms_list = postresult
        else:
            comms_list = Communications.objects.order_by('id')

        return render(request,'polls/communications.html',{"new_form":new_form,"edit_form":edit_form,'comms_list':comms_list})
```

urls.py

```
    path('communications/', views.communications, name='communications'),
```

communications.html

```
    <!--Edit Modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Create User</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{edit_form}}
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" value="update" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Screenshot (I want to click the yellow Edit on the left and have that specific row's data appear in the modal that pops up):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the initial values for the form.

```
communications = Communications.objects.get(id=**ID**) 
edit_form = EditCommunicationsForm(initial={"project":communications.project, })
```

You will get these values in html and can render at desired place. Also use one model form for both creation and editing purposes.

Comment: This makes sense, but I am not connecting the dots on how to reference my HTML file for the initial values that differ by row. For example, I get that edit_form = EditCommunicationsForm(initial={"project":"project123"}) will Default that Project field to that value, but how do I tell it that 'project_name_you_want_edit' = {{ communications.project }} within polls/communications.html?

Comment: you don't need to explicitly tell that project_name_you_want_edit' = {{ communications.project }} , by passing initial values your form will be automatically populate with initial data. As you are using default html rendering of django.

Comment: Sorry, still a little confused here... So I just tried to add that code as a placeholder and as expected I got an error saying project_name_you_want_edit is not defined. How would I add a placeholder and tell it to look at my HTML?

Comment: sorry, **project_name_you_want_edit** is just a place holder. you need to pass your own data here got from query. like in your screen shot project name is **AAA**.

Comment: Okay, so I added edit_form = EditCommunicationsForm(initial={"project":"AAA"}), which then defaults Project = AAA whenever I click on any of my rows.... I just uploaded another screenshot that shows how there are more than just AAA line items in this table. In this screenshot, I clicked on ID = 1 which should yield Project = CIT MVP but instead it still says AAA. How would I adjust this?

Comment: communications = Communications.objects.get(id=**ID**)
CommunicationsForm(initial={"project":communications.project, })

Comment: obviously you need to pass the queried data. like first query the record then pass to initial .

Comment: I've adjusted my code above.... It doesn't seem to like the **ID**  as I am getting a SyntaxError: invalid syntax error there. Am I skipping something?

Comment: **ID** mean primary key of a record like 1,2,3. As you can see it in your screen shot.

Comment: you don't need to pass the **ID** as a syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I get that but how do I get that to be variable for the different rows (e.g. if I say Communications.objects.get(id=1) and then click on row 5, how do I get it to pull the initial value for row 5 instead of 1?